# Replace multiple cell in csv python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've a large csv file(comma delimited). I would like to replace/rename few random cell with the value "NIL" to an empty string "".

I tried this to find the keyword `"NIL"` and replace with `''` empty
string. But it's giving me an empty csv file

```py
ifile = open('outfile', 'rb') 
reader = csv.reader(ifile,delimiter='\t') 
ofile = open('pp', 'wb') 
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t') 
findlist = ['NIL'] 
replacelist = [' '] 
s = ifile.read() 
for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist): 
    s = s.replace(item, replacement) 
ofile.write(s)
```

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: I just started learning python. So I'm unaware of python libraries. I'm trying to go through the whole csv file using this but it's not working.

`
ifile = open('outfile', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile,delimiter='\t')
ofile = open('pp', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')


findlist = ['NIL']
replacelist = [' ']
       
s = ifile.read()
for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist):
    s = s.replace(item, replacement)
ofile.write(s)

`

Comment: just see my code below. I did this to find my exact keyword. In my previous actions I also tried to use 2D array to go through all the cells like we used to do in C. I can read the file but couldn't replace the file with matching keyword unfortunately. @EdChum

Comment: The code you show fails because it doesn't `import csv`. If that is added in, it will write the file. When you say, the file isn't written... is it because the program crashes and you get a stack trace?

Comment: Can you be please more specific? I'm really a newbie. I'm trying to solving it by my own. I don't have any mentor to help. If you can provide me the exact solution. @tdelaney

Answer (score 0):

From seeing you code i fell you directly should

read the file

```
with open("test.csv") as opened_file:
    data = opened_file.read()
```

then use regex to change all NIL to "" or " " and save back the data to the file.

```
import re

data = re.sub("NIL"," ",data) # this code will replace NIL with " " in the data string
```

NOTE: you can give any regex instead of `NIL`

for more info see [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

EDIT 1: `re.sub` returns a new string so you need to return it to `data`.

Comment: Still not working. I tried this but the output file is same as before.@GIRISH RAMNANI

Comment: `re.sub` doesnt do inplace change of data , it returns a new instance so you have to do something like  `new_data = re.sub("NIL","",data)`

Answer (score 0):

A few tweaks and your example works. I edited your question to get rid of some indenting errors - assuming those were a cut/paste problem. The next problem is that you don't `import csv` ... but even though you create a reader and writer, you don't actually use them, so it could just be removed. So, opening in text instead of binary mode, we have

```
ifile = open('outfile')  # 'outfile' is the input file... 
ofile = open('pp', 'w') 
findlist = ['NIL'] 
replacelist = [' '] 
s = ifile.read() 
for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist): 
    s = s.replace(item, replacement) 
ofile.write(s)
```

We could add 'with' clauses and use a `dict` to make replacements more clear

```
replace_this = { 'NIL': ' '}
with open('outfile') as ifile, open('pp', 'w') as ofile: 
    s = ifile.read() 
for item, replacement in replace_this.items: 
    s = s.replace(item, replacement) 
ofile.write(s)
```

The only real problem now is that it also changes things like "NILIST" to "IST". If this is a csv with all numbers except for "NIL", that's not a problem. But you could also use the csv module to only change cells that are exactly "NIL".

```
with open('outfile') as ifile, open('pp', 'w') as ofile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    for row in reader:
        # row is a list of columns. The following builds a new list
        # while checking and changing any column that is 'NIL'. 
        writer.writerow([c if c.strip() != 'NIL' else ' ' 
            for c in row])
```